# Estimated vs actual period in Two-Way string search

Tags: strings, exact-string-matching

Both [the original paper](http://www.quretec.com/u/vilo/edu/2002-03/Tekstialgoritmid_I/Articles/Exact/Two-way-p650-crochemore.pdf) and all implementations I've seen of the Two Way string search algorithm estimate the period of the needle as $\max(|u|,|v|)$+1 (where $u$ and $v$ are the critical factors). However, this seems to be throwing a lot away; the estimated period is the amount you get to skip forward upon a mismatch in the left side, and in the worst case it's off by a factor of 2 (consider for example a needle of the form $c^ndab^n$, which factors as $u=c^nd$, $v=ab^n$, but has period $2n+2$ vs $n+2$).

Is there a good reason not to prefer just computing the exact period of the needle directly?

Comment: Presumably, the reason is efficiency.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus: Perhaps, but finding the period of the whole needle in linear time is trivial, and is a simpler version of the loop already performed twice to compute the maximal suffix under both orders on the alphabet. At one point I believed it could even be interleaved with that operation, but if so the interleaving is less trivial than I initially suspected; still at most it would incur something like a 33% increase to setup time (in practice less) for something like a 33% reduction in scanning time on needles where the estimate is poor.